# composite query to find documents in MongoDb C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am new in MongoDB. I tried to use MongoDB C# driver `find()` method and facing the following problems.

```
public IEnumerable<Ticket> GetTicketByUserId(string userId)
{
    var query = Query<Ticket>.EQ(ticket => ticket.User, userId);
    var tickets = DbCollection.Find(query);
    return tickets;
}
```

Here I want to match only for userid...
in mongodb it can be written

`db.Ticket.find({User: "-----"})` 
something like this...

But I want to check multiple field like this.

```
db.Ticket.find({User: "-----", Status:"High"})
```

bt I failed to convert it in C#. How to check multiple field like this query using Mongo C# driver. I searched but I failed to find something like this.
I have done it using linq but I want to know how to do it using `Find()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to MongoDB:

```
var tickets = from t in DbCollection.AsQueryable<Ticket>()
              where t.User == userId && t.Status == "High"
              select t;
```

If you want to use MongoQuery syntax, then just pass all sub-queries to *And* query:

```
var query = Query.And(Query<Ticket>.EQ(t => t.User, userId),
                      Query<Ticket>.EQ(t => t.Status, "High"));

var tickets = DbCollection.Find(query);
```

Comment: i have done my work using linq.. but i want to know how to use Find() method in this scenario.. sry in should mention it in question..

Comment: @SadidKhan no problem, added solution with MongoQuery syntax. But I would go with LINQ - its much more readable

Comment: thank you so much.. :) .. is there any performance issue between this two.. ?? @Sergey Berezovskiy

Comment: @SadidKhan AFAIK LINQ query gets translated into MongoQuery, and then executed. With such simple query you will probably have exactly same query generated